# Need Alternative query in Apache Hive limit

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-hive

I need alternative query for the below query.

---

Select a.name,max(a.cnt) from 
(Select name,count(name) as cnt from candidate group by name) a 
group by a.name order by 2 desc limit 1;

---

drop table if exists candidate;

create external table candidate(name string)
stored as textfile
LOCATION '/user/cloudera/test/Exercise/candidate'

load data inpath '/user/cloudera/test/candidate' overwrite into table candidate;

Sample data:

raja

raja

raja

raja

raja

Anil

Anil

Anil

Anil

Anil

Anil

Anil

Giri

Giri

Giri

mahe

mahe

I need result which name is repeated more time.
As per example above example

Anil repeated more.

To achieve the result I wrote the below query.But I am not satisfied with this query performance does anyone have alternative for this query?

Select a.name,max(a.cnt) from 
(Select name,count(name) as cnt from candidate group by name) a 
group by a.name order by 2 desc limit 1;

Thanks
Venkadesan

Answer (score 0):

```
Select name, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM candidate 
GROUP by name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Does it in one query and should run faster.